# Why can a list be used as the "key" parameter to sorted()?

Tags: python

Consider the following code snippet:

```py
matrix = {'41.0003.0005':"abc"}
for x in sorted (matrix, key=lambda x: [ int(X) for X in x.split(".") ]): print (x)
    # ...
```

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), the `sorted` function's `key` parameter *"specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in iterable."*

However, also according to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), *"Values that are not hashable, that is, values containing lists, dictionaries or other mutable types (that are compared by value rather than by object identity) may not be used as keys."*

Since this lambda function returns a list, but lists are not hashable, why are these lists allowed to be used as comparison keys in the `sorted` function?

[ ah, okay.  Some people like a lot of verbage, some people like little.  Anyway, it's absolutely reproducible - but if you're using python 3, you naturally have to put parenthesis around print's argument:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> matrix = {'41.0003.0005':"abc"}
>>> for x in sorted (matrix, key=lambda x: [ int(X) for X in x.split(".") ]): print x
...
41.0003.0005
>>>

$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Oct  8 2019, 13:06:37)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> matrix = {'41.0003.0005':"abc"}
>>> for x in sorted (matrix, key=lambda x: [ int(X) for X in x.split(".") ]): print x
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    for x in sorted (matrix, key=lambda x: [ int(X) for X in x.split(".") ]): print x
                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> for x in sorted (matrix, key=lambda x: [ int(X) for X in x.split(".") ]): print (x)
...
41.0003.0005
>>>
```

signed: original poster]

Comment: What does `None` as the second argument is supposed to do?, also, `key` must be passed as a keyword argument, so the code you posted should not even be able to execute. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Well, one thing to change is stopping calling all your variables `x`. And `sorted` has `iterable`, `key`, `reverse` as the parameters in this order. It's a good practice to use `key=` keyword `sorted(matrix, key=lambda ....)`.

Comment: `sorted ([], None, lambda x: [ int (X) for X in x.split(".")])
TypeError: sorted expected 1 arguments, got 3`

Comment: Your example is not reproducible

Comment: The question asked "why does this work?", not "why *doesn't* this work", so the stated reason for closing the question (asking for debugging help) does not apply, in my opinion. I've edited the question to clarify what I think it's asking. @n952162, If I have misunderstood the question's intent, please revert the edit.

Comment: @DeepSpace Okay, if you're using python 3, you've got to put parenthesis around print's argument:

Comment: Your two documentation links are talking about two different things, and just happen to use the term "Key" for each. A key function for a sorting algorithm is a transformation applied to each element before sorting the original by its transformation. In this case it looks like it's translating a dotted version number (something like "1.2.3") into a list of integers and sorting them against the rest. This is helpful since `sorted(['1.2.3', '1.10.3'])` doesn't work how you'd expect.

Comment: @kaya3 Thank you

Comment: In your second link, the term "Key" refers to the "key" in a dictionary's key-value pair. Since dictionaries are implemented as hash tables, it's not legal to have a non-hashable object as a key.

Comment: The first documentation link shows that sorted() takes a function that returns a key as its third argument, and the second link shows that a key may not be a list.  The problem is that the function is indeed returning a list, and it works nevertheless.

Comment: @n952162 because those two things, while using the same word, are unrelated (as explained by my two previous comments). The latter is talking about a dictionary's key, the former is talking about a key by which to sort an iterable. Notably: you can't hash your house key, a piano key, or a test's answer key either

Comment: Right.  That's the problem.  I'm hashing my house key: [ 41, 3, 5].  And sorted is happy with that

Comment: @n952162 *sigh* you're not hashing it, because you're not storing it as a dictionary key or calling `hash([41, 3, 5])`. You're just comparing it to another list. You can sort a list, and you can sort a list of lists. You just aren't allowed to hash it since it's mutable, and a hash should produce a immutable guid from the state of an object. That's not remotely necessary to compare or sort a list.

Comment: `{[41, 3, 5]: 'my house key'}` would not be valid, because dictionary keys must be hashed. `sorted([41, 3, 5])` is fine, because sorting doesn't try to hash objects. Indeed `sorted([[41, 3, 5], [41, 3, 4]])` is fine too, and produces the output you would expect.

Comment: `sorted(['41.3.5', '41.3.4'], key=lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split('.')])` sorts that list of strings the same way the list of lists would be sorted, above. It literally produces the list of lists, ties them to the strings they came from, and sorts the whole thing together.

Comment: @n952162 see this simplified sorting code https://repl.it/repls/ComposedPutridError which doesn't handle all the cases that `sorted(..., key=...)` does, but might explain it a little better.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly?  "It literally produces the list of lists, ties them to the strings they came from, and sorts the whole thing together.".  You're saying that - because the (parameter) key is a list (of ints), it does the conversion of the (matrix) key into a list of ints, so it can index apples with apples?  I may be dense, but that looks like magic to me.

Comment: There’s a notion in Python of comparability. Objects can be compared with each other to see which is lower or higher. For something like numbers that’s pretty straight forward. Lists may be less obvious, but two lists can also be compared; the rule is to compare each item in the list to each other to determine which is the “greater list”. That should explain how lists of lists can be sorted. Now, the `key=` parameter to `sorted` can simply return any value that should be used for comparison instead of the actual value. And it has nothing to do with hashing.

Comment: Okay, I see ... first of all, the second reference was not relevant because we're not comparing dictionaries, only the list of the keys of a dictionary.  Next, the same function is applied to each element of the list so we're always comparing oranges with oranges.
Thank you all.

Comment: Sometimes more verbage is indeed better...
`for key in sorted (matrix.keys(), None, lambda components: [ int(component) for component in components.split(".") ]):
    print (key)`  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are conflating two unrelated uses of the word "key".

In the quote *"Values that are not hashable ... may not be used as keys"*, the word "key" refers to the key of a dictionary. A dictionary key needs to be hashable, and its hash needs to be constant for the lifetime of the key (even if the key is a mutable object), because a Python dictionary is implemented as a [hashtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), a data structure which requires the keys to have these properties in order to have the correct behaviour as a dictionary. Python's lists are not hashable, so they cannot be used as dictionary keys.

In the `sorted` function, the "key" parameter is a function which (for each list element) should return a "comparison key", which will be used when comparing which elements should appear before which other elements in sorted order. Since the sorting algorithm only uses these keys for comparison, they only need to be *comparable*, meaning you can compare them using operations like `<`. The ordering implied by `<` must also be transitive, i.e. whenever `a < b` and `b < c`, then also `a < c`.

The comparison keys need to be comparable because the sorting algorithm works by comparing them; but the sorting algorithm doesn't try to hash the comparison keys, so they don't need to be hashable. Python's lists are comparable (they are compared in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)), so they can be used as comparison keys.